# Контейнеры в java

Tags: java

Какие стандартные контейнера позволяют найти в них элемент по его значению за O(log(n)) ?

Comment: HashSet имеет асимптотику O(1), так что не подходит. SortedSet должен подойти.

Comment: Видишь log(n) - думай сразу о дереве (с)

Answer (score 2):

HashSet/HashMap имеет асимптотику O(1) в лучшем случае, в случае коллизий там работает или список или дерево (если значений в одной node больше 8, если не ошибаюсь) и в этом случае вполне может получится и O(log(n)) в худшем случае.

Если нужно коллекция, которая в среднем выдает O(log(n)), то TreeSet/TreeMap построены на дереве, следовательно скорее всего речь именно о них. Или вам нужны вообще все возможные контейнеры в Java со временем доступа в O(log(n))? Интересуют коллекции из всяких guava и Apache (всякие PatriciaTrie и TreeList) или речь только о JDK?

Если интересно больше про коллекции посмотрите [эту мою статью](https://habrahabr.ru/company/luxoft/blog/256877/).